# Workbook is Created with two worksheets in C# and Always ask for overwriting with Book7, Book8, etc

Tags: c#, excel

I want to create an Excel Workbook with one WorkSheet, then Save the data and close it. But it creates two Sheets. Sheet2 and Sheet1. It writes the data successfully though. Everytime I delete the xlsx file manually, it asks me for overwriting Book8.xlsx even though there is not such a file with this name.

I just want one worksheet and I want to have it with a specific name too, instead of Sheet1

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Excel excel = new Excel(@"d:\Test.xlsx", 1);

        excel.WriteToCell(0, 0, "Test2");
        excel.Save();
        excel.SaveAs(@"d:\Test.xlsx");

        excel.Close();
    }
}
```

Inside Excel.cs

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using _Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace Excel
{
    class Excel
    {
        _Application excel = new _Excel.Application();

        Workbook wb;
        Worksheet ws;       

        public Excel(string path, int Sheet)
        {
            excel.Visible = false;
            wb = excel.Workbooks.Add();
            ws = wb.Worksheets.Add();
        }

        public void WriteToCell(int i, int j, string s)
        {
            i++;
            j++;
            ws.Cells[i, j].Value = s;
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            wb.Save();
        }

        public void SaveAs(string path)
        {
            wb.SaveAs(path);
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            wb.Close();
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the line `ws = wb.Worksheets.Add();` from `Excel` constructor to not create the second sheet.

```
public Excel(string path, int Sheet)
{
    excel.Visible = false;
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Add();
    ws = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];
    if (ws == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Worksheet could not be created. Check that your office installation and project references are correct.");
    }
}
```

To rename the worksheet:

```
public RenameWorksheet(string newName)
{
    ws.Name = newName;
}
```

If you delete a file from a directory, it should be deleted. However, if you are having a pop saying the file exists and do you want to replace it then my guess is it is probably a human error here. Maybe you are looking under a wrong directory? Happens to the best of us at times ;) Either way as a programmer you can choose to delete the file if it exists before creation to avoid human errors:

```
if(File.Exists(fileName))
{
    File.Delete(fileName);
}
```

or simply rename it if you don't want to replace it.

**EDIT**

On second look I realized you are creating a new file:

```
Excel excel = new Excel(@"d:\Test.xlsx", 1);
```

and then calling:

```
excel.SaveAs(@"d:\Test.xlsx");
```

what else do you expect?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It works wonderfully. I still have a problem with this message though.There is no Book8 at this directory http://i.imgur.com/OY41vjr.png.

Comment: Are you sure there is no such file? Also, before creating a new file in your `Main()` what do you get if you try `File.Exists(@"d:\Test.xlsx)`

Comment: Delete the line `excel.SaveAs(@"d:\Test.xlsx");`